# Bind objects in the lists below in WPF ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I need to binding objects of the lists below in a ***ItemsControl*** binded in a ***ScrollViewer*** in wpf .
I Provand assigning a path but I still can not binding, maybe I'm wrong ? In the subject of the first level the bind is successful , but when I go down in the lists below of the same object bind will not work.

***Xaml Scrollviewer:***

```
<surface:SurfaceScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#fff" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="scrollViewerFolderItemsSource"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=companies}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <surface:SurfaceButton Tag="{Binding CPID}" Click="Open_Click" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="Gray" Height="57" Background="White">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#fff"></Grid>
                                                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageFolder}"></Image>
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="10,3,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding companies.Attachments.Name}" Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="10,3,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}"/>
                                                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AttachmentFolders.Name}" Foreground="#565656" FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Semibold}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="10,3,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource Lato-Semibold}"/> 
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Button.Template>
                                    </surface:SurfaceButton>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </surface:SurfaceScrollViewer>
```

***CodeBehind view list binded:***

[image]

My target is binding ***Text="{Binding companies.Attachment.Name}"***

If i print ***Text="{Binding Attachment}"*** my result print on deploy is "***(Collection)***", why print ***Attachment.Name*** ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments is a Collection, to visualize a collection you should use a ListBox and use this binding `ItemsSource="{Binding companies.Attachment}"`, you also need to define the ItemTemplate for the ListBox.

With the ListBox you are able to visualize all the element, but if you want to show just the first attachment name you can use this binding `Text="{Binding companies.Attachment[0].Name}"`

or another solution could be to create a new property called AttachmentToShow of type Attachment and use this binding

`Text="{Binding AttachmentToShow.Name}"`

with this solution updating AttachmentToShow will result on an UI update.

Comment: there is a method that add dynamic index on [0] in the code ?